# SVG marker points in the wrong direction when changing line orientation

Tags: svg

I have lines with arrow head at the end. when the lines point up, right, and down, auto is working to orient the arrow head correctly. When the line goes from right to left, the arrow head ends by pointing right instead of left.
Can anyone see why that is? thanks

```
<marker id="markerArrow" viewBox="0 0 12 12" refX="0" refY="6" 
markerUnits="strokeWidth" markerWidth="8" markerHeight="6" orient="auto">
<path d="M 0 0 L 12 6 L 0 12 z" style="fill: blue;" /></marker></defs>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You correctly noticed that the direction of the marker depends on the direction of drawing the line.
Your marker is drawn with the tip to the right.

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
   width="300" height="300" viewBox="0 0 200 200" >  
  
<!--<defs>
 <marker id="markerStart" viewBox="0 0 12 12" refX="0" refY="6" 
markerUnits="strokeWidth" markerWidth="8" markerHeight="6" orient="auto">
<path d="M 0 0 L 12 6 L 0 12 z" style="fill: blue;" />
</marker> 

</defs> -->

<path d="M 0 0 L 12 6 L 0 12 z" style="fill: blue;" />
</svg>
```

The marker can be attached to the beginning of the line - `marker-start` and to the end of the line -`marker-end`

The line is drawn from the left `M10,100` to the right`L190.100`

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
   width="300" height="300" viewBox="0 0 200 200" >  
  
<defs>
<marker id="markerStart" viewBox="0 0 12 12" refX="0" refY="6" 
markerUnits="strokeWidth" markerWidth="8" markerHeight="6" orient="auto">
<path d="M 0 0 L 12 6 L 0 12 z" style="fill: blue;" />
</marker> 
</defs>

<path d="M10,50 L190,100" stroke="black" marker-start="url(#markerStart)" marker-end="url(#markerStart)"  />
<path d="M 0 0 L 12 6 L 0 12 z" style="fill: blue;"/>
</svg>
```

Now draw a line in the opposite direction from right to left

`<path d="M190,100 L10,100" />`

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
   width="300" height="300" viewBox="0 0 200 200" >  
  
<defs>
<marker id="markerStart" viewBox="0 0 12 12" refX="0" refY="6" 
markerUnits="strokeWidth" markerWidth="8" markerHeight="6" orient="auto">
<path d="M 0 0 L 12 6 L 0 12 z" style="fill: blue;" />
</marker> 
</defs>

<path d="M190,50 L10,100" stroke="black" marker-start="url(#markerStart)" marker-end="url(#markerStart)"  />
<path d="M 0 0 L 12 6 L 0 12 z" style="fill: blue;"/>
</svg>
```

There are two ways to solve this problem:

1. Draw and define in the  section two markers that are directed in different directions and use them depending on the direction of the line

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
   width="300" height="300" viewBox="0 0 200 200" >  
  
<defs>
<marker id="markerStart" viewBox="0 0 12 12" refX="0" refY="6" 
markerUnits="strokeWidth" markerWidth="8" markerHeight="6" orient="0">
<path d="M12 0 L 0 6 L 12 12 z" style="fill: red;" />
</marker>
<marker id="markerEnd" viewBox="0 0 12 12" refX="0" refY="6" 
markerUnits="strokeWidth" markerWidth="8" markerHeight="6" orient="auto">
<path d="M 0 0 L 12 6 L 0 12 z" style="fill: blue;" />
</marker> 


</defs>

<path d="M10,100 L190,100" stroke="black" marker-start="url(#markerStart)" marker-end="url(#markerEnd)"  />

     <!-- Marker Start -->
<path d="M12 0 L 0 6 L 12 12 z" style="fill: red;" />
</svg>
```

2. Rotate one of the markers 180 degrees `orient ="180"`

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
   width="300" height="300" viewBox="0 0 200 200" >  
  
<defs>
<marker id="markerStart" viewBox="0 0 12 12" refX="0" refY="6" 
markerUnits="strokeWidth" markerWidth="8" markerHeight="6" orient="auto">
<path d="M 0 0 L 12 6 L 0 12 z" style="fill: blue;" />
</marker> 

<marker id="markerEnd" viewBox="0 0 12 12" refX="0" refY="6" 
markerUnits="strokeWidth" markerWidth="8" markerHeight="6" orient="180">
<path d="M 0 0 L 12 6 L 0 12 z" style="fill: red;" />
</marker>
</defs>

<path d="M10,100 L190,100" stroke="black" marker-start="url(#markerEnd)" marker-end="url(#markerStart)"  />

</svg>
```

Update

**Marker-mid**

Used only on kinks of the line. On a completely straight line it will not be visible 
In the example below, `marker-mid ="url(#markerRight)` is red

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
   width="300" height="300" viewBox="0 0 200 200" >  
  
<defs>
<marker id="markerRight" viewBox="0 0 12 12" refX="6" refY="6" 
markerUnits="strokeWidth" markerWidth="10" markerHeight="10" orient="auto-start-reverse">
<path d="M12 0 L 0 6 L 12 12 z" style="fill: red;" />
</marker>
<marker id="markerLeft" viewBox="0 0 12 12" refX="6" refY="6" 
markerUnits="strokeWidth" markerWidth="10" markerHeight="10" orient="auto">
<path d="M 0 0 L 12 6 L 0 12 z" style="fill: blue;" />
</marker> 
</defs>

<path fill="none" d="M10,100 50,50 100,150 180,50 190,150" stroke="black" marker-start="url(#markerLeft)" marker-mid="url(#markerRight)" marker-end="url(#markerLeft)"  />

</svg>
```

Comment: you can also use orient="auto-start-reverse". Firefox supports that, not sure about other UAs.

Comment: thanks both!! auto-start-reverse didn't seem to do it but now I will will change the orientation  as per Alexandr_TT using the 180 thanks!!

Comment: well, found the issue with reversing the orientation using either 180 or auto-start-reverse. they do not appear to work in chrome but seems they ARE working in IE

Comment: well, now it's working in Chrome as well. No idea why

Comment: @Nancymic Try different approaches, analyze the results and draw conclusions

Comment: @Alexandr_TT  I was having the line turn back around by mistake, which you couldn't actually see as the line was over itself. The line was doing a 180 and doubling back over itself, and thus the arrow was oriented correctly all along. Nice SVG work up there though thanks again Trying to write paths that are really flexible using vars and it's really hard to do (for me).